# Closing Accordion when click another Accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

Wrote this JQuery accordion, wanting to close the accordion once another is selected, how do I do this...

```
$(function () {
    $("td.collapsable").find(".hidden").hide();
    $("table").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ($target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1) {
            $target.slideUp();
        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().find(".hidden").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can u add the same in jsfiddle, so that it will be easier to solve your problem

Comment: @user2282633 please put your html and script in a jsfiddle

Comment: I would add a click function that does something to the effect of $(this).siblings().slideup();  I may be missing something but it should be the right direction.

Comment: sorry here you go guys http://jsfiddle.net/6Y6vf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this:  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y6vf/1/)**

```
$(function () {
    $("td.collapsable").find(".hidden").hide();
    $("table").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target).closest("tr").next().find("td.collapsable").find(".hidden");
        $("td.collapsable").find(".hidden:visible").not($target).slideUp();
        $target.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick thing I made, I don't know if it can be applied in you're case, since you didn't showed us the code, but someone might find it useful. The same effect can be achieved in many ways, I chose to to it like this.

[**jsFiddle Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3WsHX/14/)

```
$('span').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('.level1').slideDown(200);
    $(this).parent('li').siblings('li').children('span').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').siblings('li').children('.level1').slideUp(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `.toggler` to your `TR` elements that are clickable:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y6vf/3/)**</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $("td.collapsable").find(".hidden").hide();
    $(".toggler").click(function(){
         var myHiddenEl = $(this).next('tr').find('.hidden');
         var toggAnim   = myHiddenEl.css("display")=='none' ? "slideDown" : "slideUp" ;
         $('.hidden').slideUp();
         myHiddenEl[toggAnim]();
    });
});
```